# Go to quickfix next/previous (cnext/cprevious) relative to current file position?

Tags: quickfix

Is there any built-in way to jump to the next or previous error in the quickfix/location list relative to the current cursor position?

Say my quickfix list looks like:

```
---quickfix list---
a.txt - line 1
a.txt - line 2
b.txt - line 6
b.txt - line 7
```

I am currently in `b.txt` on line 1. If I try `:cnext` Vim will jump to `a.txt` on line 1.

Instead I would prefer to jump to `b.txt` on line 6 (and whatever column is specified in the qf list)

```
b.txt - 1 => b.txt - 6
```

Comment: Note, Vim patch [8.1.1256](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/3ff33114d70fc0f7e9c3187c5fec9028f6499cf3) and patch [8.1.1275](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/cf6a55c4b0cbf38b0c3fbed5ffd9a3fd0d2ede0e) added the `:cbefore`, `:cabove`, `cbelow` and `cafter` commands (together with the respecting locationlist commands `l...`). See also the now (deleted answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built in way to do file specific `:cnext`. You would have to roll your own function/command to do such a task.

Here is my interpretation of `:Cfnext`:

```
command! -bar -count=1 Cfnext exe 'cc'.(get(get(filter(map(getqflist(), 'extend(v:val, {"idx": v:key})'), 'bufname(v:val.bufnr) == expand("%") && line(".") <= v:val.lnum && col(".") < v:val.col'), 0, {}), 'idx', getqflist({'idx':1}).idx-1)+<count>)
```

Here is a cleaned up and more complete version:

```
command! -bar -count=1 Cfnext execute <SID>cfnext(<count>, 'qf')
command! -bar -count=1 Cfprev execute <SID>cfnext(<count>, 'qf', 1)
command! -bar -count=1 Lfnext execute <SID>cfnext(<count>, 'loc')
command! -bar -count=1 Lfprev execute <SID>cfnext(<count>, 'loc', 1)

function! s:cfnext(count, list, ...) abort
  let reverse = a:0 && a:1 
  let func = 'get' . a:list . 'list'
  let params = a:list == 'loc' ? [0] : []
  let cmd = a:list == 'loc' ? 'll' : 'cc'

  let items = call(func, params)
  if len(items) == 0
    return 'echoerr ' . string('E42: No Errors')
  endif

  call map(items, 'extend(v:val, {"idx": v:key + 1})')
  if reverse
    call reverse(items)
  endif

  let [bufnr, cmp] = [bufnr('%'), reverse ? 1 : -1]
  let context = [line('.'), col('.')]
  if v:version > 800 || has('patch-8.0.1112')
    let current = call(func, extend(copy(params), [{'idx':1}])).idx
  else
    redir => capture | execute cmd | redir END
    let current = str2nr(matchstr(capture, '(\zs\d\+\ze of \d\+)'))
  endif
  call add(context, current)

  call filter(items, 'v:val.bufnr == bufnr && s:cmp(context, [v:val.lnum, v:val.col, v:val.idx]) == cmp')

  let idx = get(get(items, 0, {}), 'idx', 'E553: No more items')

  if type(idx) == type(0)
    return cmd . idx
  else
     return 'echoerr' . string(idx)
  endif
endfunction

function! s:cmp(a, b)
  for i in range(len(a:a))
    if a:a[i] < a:b[i]
      return -1
    elseif a:a[i] > a:b[i]
      return 1
    endif
  endfor
  return 0
endfunction
```

For more help see:

```
:h getqflist()
:h filter()
:h index()
:h :cc
:h bufname()
:h expand()
:h map()
:h extend()
```

Comment: You could simplify very slightly with `let qf = map(qf` => `call map(qf` and same with `filter(`.

Comment: It looks like the ALE plugin always set the column number to 1 (or at least, some ALE checkers do). So if it's not working, you may to consider removing that part. You can also replace `<=` with `<` to jump "over" the current item (instead of activating it again). Also, I think `bufname(v:val.bufnr) == fname` is the same as `v:val.bufnr == bufnr('')`?

Comment: [Here is my version btw](https://github.com/Carpetsmoker/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/list.vim#L21), it adds better errors and works for both the quickfix and location list.

Comment: @Mass & @Carpetsmoker, I have cleaned up code to address the issues you both pointed out. @Carpetsmoker, I think you want to be column aware. Otherwise you can not use this with `:vimgrep/pat/g %` when you have multiple matches on the same line.

Comment: Hm, I just tried again and I have various issues if I add the `col('.')` check (skipping entries, not going back to the first). I don't know if this is a problem in my code or ALE, I need to investigate in more depth later. For me personally it's not an issue as I rarely have cases with two or more items on the same line (I never use e.g. `:vimgrep`).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, I am guessing your checker is giving you multiple entries with the same line & column data. I have added the qf/loc list idx to my comparison so no entries will be skipped. You may not use `:vimgrep`, but you might use `ag` or ripgrep.  Both tools take the `--vimgrep` option which allows multiple matches per line. Using `--vimgrep` is also the recommended vim config for both tools.

Answer (score 3):

The patch [8.1.1256](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.1256) has just added the commands `:cabove`, `:cbelow`, `:labove` and `:lbelow`, which, I think, do what you want.

As usual, the commands prefixed by `c` operate on a quickfix list, and the ones prefixed by `l` operate on a location list. And here, `above` makes the cursor jump to the previous entry, while `below` makes it jump to the next one.

---

The commands accept a count, so you can skip some entries when you jump.
For example, `:3cbelow` should make you jump to the third entry after your current position.

---

There are some caveats though.

The entries in the quickfix list must be sorted by their buffer number and line number. I think Vim's default commands – which populate a quickfix list – do that by default, like `:vimgrep` and `:helpgrep`; but it may not be the case with a quickfix list populated by a custom command (provided by a third-party plugin for example).

Also, if several entries are on the same line, it seems that only the first one is considered.

---

Relevant help:

```
                                                        *:cabo* *:cabove*
:[count]cabo[ve]        Go to the [count] error above the current line in the
                        current buffer.  If [count] is omitted, then 1 is
                        used.  If there are no errors, then an error message
                        is displayed.  Assumes that the entries in a quickfix
                        list are sorted by their buffer number and line
                        number. If there are multiple errors on the same line,
                        then only the first entry is used.  If [count] exceeds
                        the number of entries above the current line, then the
                        first error in the file is selected.

                                                        *:lab* *:labove*
:[count]lab[ove]        Same as ":cabove", except the location list for the
                        current window is used instead of the quickfix list.
```